# Вывести несколько строк через itextSharp

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Нужно создать файл PDF с фоновой картинкой на которой будут выведены несколько строк текста. Paragraph не использую тк он перекрывается фоновой картинкой. Нашел такой вариант через PdfContentByte, но он выводи ВСЕ в одну строку, не переводя каретку на новую.

```
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 14);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(35, 615);
                cb.ShowText(string.Join("\r\n", ListName<string>));

                cb.EndText();
```

вопросов собственно 2 - как вывести содержимое ListName построчно, или 2 вариант как задать фоновой картинке слой что бы она не перекрывала текста? Подобное перекрытие работает только когда добавляю текст, новые картинки на фоновой отображаются корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямого ответа я так и не нашел, но такой код вполне рабочий. И может быть использован если нужно наложить текст на картинку - фона. Если использовать просто Paragraph картинка перекроет текст.

```
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                int fontSize = 14;
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, fontSize);

                for (int i=0; i<OD.OrdersData().Count; i++)
                {
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(135, 615 - i * fontSize);
                    cb.ShowText(OD.OrdersData()[i]);
                }
                cb.EndText();
```

Comment: Вы бы прокомментировали магические числа

Comment: новый ShowText опускается на 14px по оси У тк для каждой строки SetTextMatrix меняется. Не знаю даже что тут комментировать.

Comment: ну я так вижу связанность между размером шрифта и размером смещения

Comment: размер шрифта не изменяется.  14 это и размер и смещение.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли, я имел ввиду что размер строки в данном случае и есть смещение. я бы наверно выше по коду создал переменную что бы в случае чего менять в одном месте а не в 2. но это так придирки

Comment: Вы правы, поправил код